# Jumbotrom in center

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I need jumbotrom in the center , used aligné center and worked however , the text was also in the center , and accurate text in left .

```
        <div class="container" align="center"  >
        <div class="jumbotron"style="max-width:700px" >
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using BootStrap, then use the BootStrap grid:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <div class="jumbotron" class="text-center">
    </div><!-- .col-xs-8 -->
    <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
  </div><!-- .row -->
</div><!-- .container -->
```

Comment: Tks! Pc worked perfect, but not mobile, become very narrow, with lots of space around the edges.
see my test, has no password
http://www.diveletro.esy.es/usuarios/login.php
http://www.diveletro.esy.es/usuarios/escritorio.php

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I use so perfect and work :

```
        <<div class="container" style="max-width:700px" >
        <div class="jumbotron" style="center" >
```